# change HTML element place to another place javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to take img.fnone and replace  it under span.ddlabel element via JavaScript or jquery 
is there any function to do that

```
  <span id="flat_title" class="ddTitleText ">
    <img class="fnone" src="images/pinc.png">
    <span class="ddlabel">A</span>
    <span class="description" style="display: none;"></span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
var targetSPAN=$('#flat_title');
var image=$('img.fnone', targetSPAN);

$('span.ddlabel', targetSPAN).append(image);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJpj/31/)

Comment: Why bother to clone and remove? If you append it to somewhere else it simply moves, it's not a copy.

Comment: yes it's working fine, but what if there are many elements with the same class names in the page and i want to do the same action

Comment: @thehero75 For that you would have to use an `ID`, or loop over each of the elements and find the correct item you want to move it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('span .ddlabel').append('<img class="fnone" src="images/pinc.png">');
        $('#flat_title img:first').remove()

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of element.appendChild method.

```
<span id="flat_title" class="ddTitleText ">
    <img class="fnone" src="images/pinc.png" />
    <span class="ddlabel">A</span>
    <span class="description" style="display: none;"></span>
</span>
<div>
    <button id="abc">Click to replace</button>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('flat_title'),
    img = document.getElementsByClassName('fnone')[0],
    description = document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0];

    parent.appendChild(img);
    parent.appendChild(description);
})
</script>
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/fWK67/

Answer (score 0):

Use html()

```
var html=$("img.fnone").html();
$("span.ddlabel").html(html);
$("img.fnone").remove();
```